# MS SQL linked servers mecanism in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there linked servers mecanism in postgresql like ms sql server?
What is the best way to execute query to "information_schema.columns" on 2 different postgresql servers to compare their table stucture?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/dblink.html

Comment: In my experience the question to "compare table structures" indicates the wrong approach to deploy schema changes. In the long run you should investigate the use of [schema management tools](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Change_management_tools_and_techniques)  like [Liquibase](http://liquibase.org/), [Sqitch](https://github.com/sqitchers/sqitch) or Flyway to manage your schema migrations

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
I need to "compare table structures" not for schema migrations. I need this for task associated with ETL.
I had source database and our database and I want check difference between them.
For the link to dblink thank you very much.